# App Files on Mac OS X - Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos

I have been using an App (Visual Studio Code) on Mac OS X for several months now. Somehow I've gotten the app into an unusable state on Mac OS X. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it. However, that did not work. It looks like my user settings and preferences persisted though. Which means that there are some files or settings somewhere on Mac OS X.

Where do those files / settings get stored? I would like to remove them and start from scratch and see if that fixes my issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

To completely remove Visual Studio Code you should delete the following files and folders:

```
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app  
/private/tmp/VSCode Crashes  
~/.vscode  
~/Library/Application Support/Code  
~/Library/Caches/Code 
~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.*  
~/Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState
```

*monitored with [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/) (OK it's a 404, but the domain still exists)*

Comment: Hi there, I removed the 1st one manually, and then the rest through the `Terminal` window using `rm -rf`. Is this enough or should I use a different command?